# Error JDBC exception executing SQL

Tags: java, sql, spring-boot, spring, hibernate

necesito ayuda con este error: JDBC exception executing SQL

```
"message": "JDBC exception executing SQL [SELECT new com.perea.pereaapp.dto.GananciasDTO (SUM(ventas.cantidad * (ventas.precio_venta - ventas.precio_compra)) AS ganancias_netas, SUM(ventas.cantidad * ventas.precio_compra) AS costos_a_reponer, SUM((ventas.cantidad * (ventas.precio_venta - ventas.precio_compra)) + (ventas.cantidad * ventas.precio_compra)) as ganancias_brutas) FROM ventas WHERE ventas.fecha BETWEEN ? AND ?]; SQL [n/a]"
```

Ese es el error que me arroja Insomnia a la hora de hacer la peticion. El endpoint que estoy usando es:

http://localhost:8080/api/ventas/ganancias?fechaInicio=2022-01-01&fechaFin=2022-12-30

Mi clase repositorio es la siguiente:

```
@Repository
public interface VentaRepository extends JpaRepository<Venta, Long> {
    @Query(value = "SELECT new com.perea.pereaapp.dto.GananciasDTO " +
            "SUM(ventas.cantidad * (ventas.precio_venta - ventas.precio_compra)) AS ganancias_netas, " +
            "SUM(ventas.cantidad * ventas.precio_compra) AS costos_a_reponer, " +
            "SUM((ventas.cantidad * (ventas.precio_venta - ventas.precio_compra)) + (ventas.cantidad * ventas.precio_compra)) as ganancias_brutas " +
            "FROM ventas " +
            "WHERE ventas.fecha BETWEEN ?1 AND ?2", nativeQuery = true)
    GananciasDTO obtenerGanancias(Date fechaInicio, Date fechaFin);
```

Mi clase controlador:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/ventas")
public class VentaController {

    private final VentaService ventaService;

    public VentaController(VentaService ventaService) {
        this.ventaService = ventaService;
    }

    @GetMapping("/ganancias")
    public GananciasDTO obtenerGanancias(@RequestParam("fechaInicio") @DateTimeFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd") String fechaInicio,
                                         @RequestParam("fechaFin") @DateTimeFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd") String fechaFin) {
        SimpleDateFormat formato = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        Date fechaInicioDate;
        Date fechaFinDate;
        try {
            fechaInicioDate = formato.parse(fechaInicio);
            fechaFinDate = formato.parse(fechaFin);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        return ventaService.obtenerGanancias(fechaInicioDate, fechaFinDate);
    }
```

La descripcion de mi tabla ventas:

[image: Tabla ventas]

Y la clase GananciasDTO:

```
@Data
public class GananciasDTO {
    private BigDecimal gananciasNetas;
    private BigDecimal costosAReponer;
    private BigDecimal gananciasBrutas;

public GananciasDTO(BigDecimal gananciasNetas, BigDecimal costosAReponer, BigDecimal gananciasBrutas) {
        this.gananciasNetas = gananciasNetas;
        this.costosAReponer = costosAReponer;
        this.gananciasBrutas = gananciasBrutas;
    }
```

Gracias de antemano por la ayuda.

Comment: Hola, mi consejo es que hagas las cosas de una en una, no deberías de tratar de hacer todo en la sentencia de SQL, eso va en contra del principio de responsabilidad única y en parte es lo que te esta haciendo pasar tantas dificultades, recupera de base de datos los registros primero y luego insertalos con SETS en el DTO. Respecto a tu error de SQL un poco en la misma línea, es porque en el comando select estas declarando un objeto JAVA que no existe. Te recomiendo hacer las cosas por separado. (el sum es mas eficiente en SQL así que ahí esta bien)

Comment: La base de datos no tiene ni idea de que es ese dto y no te va a entregar una instancia de una clase. Cuando implementas cosas en el repositorio, mapeas cosas de persistencia en clases java mediante anotaciones, pero es responsabilidad de la aplicación, no de la BD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cuando utilizas la anotación `@Query` y el parámetro `nativeQuery = true` estas especificando que la consulta SQL que vas a utilizar es nativa al Gestor de Base de Datos, y lo que estas ejecutando es una consulta con JPQL. Para que se ejecute la consulta JPQL puedes quitar el parametro `nativeQuery = true` ya que por defecto es `false` o puedes crear la consulta SQL y remplazar la que tienes he hibernate se encargara de Mapear las columnas al DTO siempre y cuando tengan el mismo nombre.

Comment: Gracias, asi solucione:
`
@Query(value = "SELECT new com.perea.pereaapp.dto.GananciasDTO(" +
            "SUM(v.cantidad * (v.precioVenta - v.precioCompra))," +
            "SUM(v.cantidad * v.precioCompra)," +
            "SUM((v.cantidad * (v.precioVenta - v.precioCompra)) + (v.cantidad * v.precioCompra))" +
            ")" +
            "FROM Venta v " +
            "WHERE v.fecha BETWEEN :fechaInicio AND :fechaFin")
    GananciasDTO obtenerGanancias(@Param("fechaInicio") Date fechaInicio, @Param("fechaFin") Date fechaFin);`

Answer (score 0):

La solucion fue hacer el Query JPQL:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT new com.perea.pereaapp.dto.GananciasDTO(" +
            "SUM(v.cantidad * (v.precioVenta - v.precioCompra))," +
            "SUM(v.cantidad * v.precioCompra)," +
            "SUM((v.cantidad * (v.precioVenta - v.precioCompra)) + (v.cantidad * v.precioCompra))" +
            ")" +
            "FROM Venta v " +
            "WHERE v.fecha BETWEEN :fechaInicio AND :fechaFin")
    GananciasDTO obtenerGanancias(@Param("fechaInicio") Date fechaInicio, @Param("fechaFin") Date fechaFin);
```

Lo raro es que el intellij me marca el siguiente error pero aun asi me funciona:

```
Cannot resolve constructor 'com.perea.pereaapp.dto.GananciasDTO(java.lang.Long, java.lang.Long, java.lang.Long)'
```

Y si llego a modificar el constructor que reciba datos de tipo Long, entonces ahi si falla, que raro